# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 26 bytes while decrypting encoded text

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I am trying to decrypt a request encrypted using AES algorithm with the RSA encrypted AES secret key. The **encryptedText** is the text which I have to decode using **encryptedAESKeyStringinString** key.

```
String encryptedText = "motnHul049AJSIo5RiOr7Njg3gV85LSR7DxxTjT6UlN_Vdi0q7hw9XDTUyiJ7XCtaObJDOWPwXGeT73JQKwN-GW6Pg6fkgyRlbmqNM23_DjqFQG7NqhhwdRfVJ4FfGnB1sZMcsSi0YwtKVOfTQu11coQm-LnWSW3o05-A4B7X4";
```

// Generate public and private keys using RSA

```
Key privateKey = getPrivate("KeyPair/key.jks");        
System.out.println("Private key :" + privateKey);
Key publicKey = getPublic("KeyPair/key.jks");
System.out.println("Public key :" + publicKey);
```

//Encrypted AES secret key using RSA public key

```
String encryptedAESKeyStringinString = "SGvzL3jbTucB6mFSrGDHGI19OKuLe2u0miGnmb6EfgIHgiWqGfvGI5hd2U8-owYKThORbY6IZWyUsFKFc2CsegMKGkUBbnKHz-BUbrC5jNPHeW2LxNW_SLKZMmVciwWqHtcsQkUhGn1ZpEwgYp7NccP2qQJ1K5wY0G22ssoXsr6_gf4aMAafpP_EU8bV6yfOziaNWdOI0mkBshC6uYi2xibCBFWhP0HYouxEjuoLa7oXDSr1-Pol7S4tFibv8P92GlEqHuspjkBEk-crBVEMwPYZ5CjlVg0a8NXofvRYJIPOWHFDP03ALnKUmhGDv5pq7qbyhM-GwLFDncOU466VTw";
```

//Decryption of AES key

```
String decryptedAESKeyString = decryptAESKey(encryptedAESKeyStringinString, privateKey);
System.out.println("Decrypted AES key with RSA "+decryptedAESKeyString);
```

// Now decrypt data using the decrypted AES key!

```
String decryptedText = decryptTextUsingAES(encryptedText, decryptedAESKeyString);
System.out.println("decrypted: " + decryptedText);
```

//decryptTextUsingAES() method

```
public static String decryptTextUsingAES(String encryptedText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {

    //byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(aesKeyString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
    System.out.println("decodedKey->"+decodedKey);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
    //byte[] encPass = Base64.decodeBase64(aesKeyString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    //SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
    //SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    System.out.println("AES key :"+ originalKey);

    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encryptedText));

    return new String(bytePlainText);
}
```

//decryptAESKey() method

```
private static String decryptAESKey(String encryptedAESKey, Key privateKey) throws Exception {

    byte[] encBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encryptedAESKey.trim().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("encBytes=="+encBytes); 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

    return new String(cipher.doFinal(encBytes));
}
```

//Getting public and private key

```
public static Key getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {

    String password = "123456";
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
    String alias = "rib_pub_priv_ob";
    Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());        

    return key;
}
```

//https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html

```
public static Key getPublic(String filename) throws Exception {

    String password = "123456";
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
    Enumeration aliases = keystore.aliases();
    //LOG.info("Loaded aliases..........."+aliases);
    String aliasName = null;
    if (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {            
        aliasName = (String)aliases.nextElement();          
    }
    //String alias = "cib.icicibank.com";
    String alias = "rib_pub_priv_ob";
    Key key = keystore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey(); 

    // Get certificate of public key
    java.security.cert.Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

    // Get public key
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    //System.out.println("Publickey->"+publicKey);

    return key;
}
```

//Output

```
Private key success
Private key :sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@ffd2dcac
Public key success
Public key :Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
      modulus: 18213722380296769419176290383978262259711510121564750763778723301212945343757780419548592815669767026269432578044929215041238216136582555682984918038025714579636338218912893485917045613716952330026484856385185507103281153339648026845099146147505703575013284525178116844264542711761691005405946223414048773983620990969094260489552973361717030169183023097170355217065004855506605954167676904790917459796930427392967698905896378678786481959179236540862580781084688615759803403218899513555331743203995382479570969849672080854328076415494976227353539015464213594405750368178401939001834233806304211309666500156295537454433
      public exponent: 65537
    encBytes==[B@2d6d8735
    Decrypted AES key with RSA Pf03zku5GNElJlOXAZkYRg6LbeZttkMKCdL
    decodedKey->[B@de0a01f
    AES key :javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17c6b
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 26 bytes
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:87)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:94)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:467)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:313)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:802)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
        at demo123.AESwithRSA.decryptTextUsingAES(AESwithRSA.java:144)
        at demo123.AESwithRSA.main(AESwithRSA.java:79)
```

Comment: `System.out.println(someByteArray)` is useless. You should better convert the byte[] to hex for printing. Also using AES in ECB is grossly negligent. Except for academic purposes ECB mode should never be used anymore.

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. Use a byte array and save all the round-trips to `char` and back, which are not guaranteed to be symmetrical.